# Improving Ubuntu speed and stability on VirtualBox running on a Mac

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth, virtualization, ram, mac

Good day--

I just started running Ubuntu 20.04.2 via VirtualBox 6.1.22 on a 2017 MacBook Pro with a 3.5 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB of RAM, and macOS 11.3.1. I've allocated 11.5 GB of RAM, maxed out video memory at 128 MB, and allocated 2 processors to the virtual machine. When I run the virtual machine, most of my Mac apps are closed (and the ones that are running are not memory or processor intensive).

There's a substantial lag time though from when I hit the keyboard or move the mouse until when the action is reflected on the screen (both devices are Bluetooth). The problem is more significant when I'm trying to open or close an app, scroll with the mouse, or use the mouse to lay out the contents of a screenshot. Additionally, I'm mostly running only Firefox and Brave on Ubuntu (simultaneously), but still experience a fair amount of crashes.

Any suggestions for how I can make my Ubuntu virtual machine faster and more stable? Thanks!

Comment: The first suggestion is to follow the rule of never allocate more than half of the resources to any VM, both CPU and RAM. The second suggestion is to install the guest additions.

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto.